# nvim - deactivating mouse

Tags: linux, neovim

can you help me? I Want to deactivate the mouse in nvim. It should neither scroll, nor change the cursor position.

I added the following lines to my init.lua, to disable scrolling by mouse:

```
for _, amplitude in ipairs({ "", "S-", "C" }) do
    for _, direction in ipairs({ "Up", "Down", "Left", "Right" }) do
    for _, modus in ipairs({ "", "i" }) do
        vim.keymap.set(modus, "<" .. amplitude .. "ScrollWheel" .. direction .. ">", "<Nop>", { })
    end
    end
end
```

This works, and scrolling is disabled. However, I can still change the curser position by point and click. To disable this, I also added the following line:

```
vim.opt.mouse = ""
```

Now, I can't change the curser by point and click, but scrolling is active again. I don't understand why? Is there a way to deactivate both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The reason for this behavior is that scrolling on touchpads is remaped to the arrow keys by the terminal emulator. Hence, if I disable mouse nvim still gets the arrow key information.

Conequently a solution was to nomap the arrow keys and disable mouse:

```
vim.keymap.set("", "<up>", "<nop>", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set("", "<down>", "<nop>", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set("i", "<up>", "<nop>", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set("i", "<down>", "<nop>", { noremap = true })

vim.opt.mouse = ""
```